# Unable to increase

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to create a test class however unable to reach more than 73% :

```
 public with sharing class DebtFileSearchController{

    public list<ctDebtFile__c> debtFile {get;set;}
    public string oagFileNumber {get;set;}

    public DebtFileSearchController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    }

    public void search(){

        string searchQuery='select name, id, OAG_File_Number__c, Description__c from ctDebtFile__c ';

        if(!String.isBlank(oagFileNumber)){
//*** start not covered ***

            if(oagFileNumber.containsAny('*')){
                String wildcard = oagFileNumber.replace('*', '');
                searchQuery = searchQuery + ' where OAG_File_Number__c like \'%' + wildcard.trim() + '%\'';
            }else{
                searchQuery = searchQuery + ' where OAG_File_Number__c = agFileNumber ';
//*** end not covered ***
            }
     }
```

Test Class involved:

```
 @isTest
private class DebtFileSearchController_Test {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        ctDebt__c d = new ctDebt__c();
        insert d;

        ctDebtFile__c df = new ctDebtFile__c();
        df.Debt__c = d.Id;
        df.Description__c = 'Test';
        df.OAG_File_Number__c = 'XX123';
        insert df;

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(df);

        DebtFileSearchController controller = new DebtFileSearchController(sc);

        PageReference pageRef = Page.DebtFileSearch;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber','*XX*');

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        controller.search();
        controller.clear();

nikunj21gupta: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber','XX123');

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        controller.search();

       controller.clear();

        } 

            static testMethod void myUnitTest1() {

        ctDebt__c d = new ctDebt__c();
        insert d;

        ctDebtFile__c df = new ctDebtFile__c();
        df.Debt__c = d.Id;
        df.Description__c = 'Test';
        df.OAG_File_Number__c = 'XX12390';
        insert df;

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(df);

        DebtFileSearchController controller = new DebtFileSearchController(sc);

        PageReference pageRef = Page.DebtFileSearch;

        ApexPages.currentPage().getP
nikunj21gupta: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber','*XX*');

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        controller.search();

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber','XX12390');

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        controller.search();

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber','XYZ123');

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        controller.search();
        controller.clear();
             }

  }
```

Comment: If you want help with this, please help us by marking the lines where you don't have coverage with something obvious like `//*** start not covered ***` and `//*** end not covered ***`, etc.

Comment: updated @crmprogdev

Comment: You're going to have to learn to format code one of these days.

Comment: remember best practice - use system.assert to verify the controller returns the expected mocked records. Proof point: `...where OAG_File_Number__c = agFileNumber` is not going to get you what you expect.

Comment: and actually test code and not just execute it......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your test is not reaching that particular piece of code is because `oagFileNumber` is a property inside your custom controller and you never set that value.  `!String.isBlank(oagFileNumber)` is false every time in your code because of this.

Based on your test class, I'm going to make a couple of assumptions:

1. You have a page called `DebtFileSearch` which has a parameter called `oagFileNumber`
2. In your controller, you are expecting to pull this parameter and construct a search query based on the value of `oagFileNumber`

In order for your controller to get the `oagFileNumber` parameter from the page, the following line needs to be somewhere in your code:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oagFileNumber')
```

Based on the fact that you have an `oagFileNumber` property in your controller, it seems to me that you need to do the following in your controller's constructor:

```
oagFileNumber = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oagFileNumber')
```

This way, when the controller is created for a page, it will grab this parameter value.  When you search (assuming the controller has successfully grabbed the parameter, which you should test for), `!String.isBlank(oagFileNumber)` should come back true and your code will continue to the inside of your if-statement.

To test this, you'll need to simulate this page by doing something similar to this:

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.DebtFileSearch'));
```

So, this is now your current page and now you can set parameters on that page:

```
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber', '<test-value>');
```

It looks like you are sort of doing this, but I think you need to fix the order in which you're doing things because it looks like you're trying to set a parameter on a page that you haven't set as your current page yet.  Also, if you set the `oagFileNumber` in your controller constructor, you won't want to create that controller until you have set these values.  (You could, alternatively, get the parameter in your `search()` method and keep the controller creation at the top of your test method).

Hopefully that makes sense.

P.S.  @crmprogdev wrote a good answer that pertains to Best Practice and I would strongly suggest writing your tests that way.  My answer is specific to the issue you are running in to.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In order to increase your coverage, you'll want to have at least 2 methods and perhaps 3. You were missing any curly braces at the end of your method to which I added one. There should be another one to close the end of your class. That said, you have an opening if statement that you test:

```
if(!String.isBlank(oagFileNumber)){
```

And then your code coverage ends. Your class needs to add coverage to test the additional if statements. That requires at least one more method as you can only test the else statement using a 2nd method.

It appears to me that the reason you're not getting the coverage is that you're trying to clear the controller and not using separate test methods. Use a structure like below and that should solve your problem.

```
 @isTest
private class DebtFileSearchController_Test {

    static testMethod void UnitTestStringisBlankPositive() {

    }

    static testMethod void UnitTestStringisBlankNegative() {

    }

    static testMethod void UnitTestStringPosFileNumbercontainsPos() {

    }

    static testMethod void UnitTestStringPosFileNumbercontainsNeg() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks . However Do I need to use         ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oagFileNumber','XX12390'); or just run the query on the basis of insertion and check the values in all of the 3 methods Thanks

Comment: since it's a page controller you're working with, you'll want to set the parameters for the current page in order to pass them to the controller. Once they're set, the controller should have a get method to retrieve them which you're doing using an Apex Properties method.